# Can't edit root_blip of fetched wavelet

Tags: google-wave

When i edit root_blip of wavelet everything works fine, but if i fetch the wavelet nothing happens neither in googleWave nor logs (no errors occured), although "wave_list.reply(text)" works. I have made myRobot.setup_oauth()

```
def OnWaveletSelfAdded(event, wavelet):  
  text = "123"  
  wave_list = myRobot.fetch_wavelet(wave_id="googlewave.com!w+O5yFQIteC", wavelet_id="googlewave.com!conv+root")  
  wave_list.submit_with(wavelet)  
  root_blip = wave_list.root_blip  
  root_blip.all().delete()  
  root_blip.append("WaveList\n" + text)  
  logging.info("root_blip.wave_id: %s" % root_blip.wave_id)
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried myRobot.submit(wave_list) - also no results

Answer (score 0):

```
  wave_list = myRobot.fetch_wavelet(wave_id = wave_id, wavelet_id="googlewave.com!conv+root")  
  root_blip = wave_list.root_blip  
  root_blip.all().delete()  
  root_blip.append("WaveList:\n")
  myRobot.submit(wave_list)
```

solved...